# win10 yarn cant find typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a git repo that I'm supposed to launch with the command `react-scripts start`. When I run this command I get this response saying typescript cant be found:

```
react-scripts start
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have typescript installed.
Please install typescript by running npm install typescript.
If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files).
```

I have tried installing typescript in command prompt with npm i typescript, npm i -g typescript, yarn add typescript, yarn global add typescript, and "choco install typescript".

I am able to run typescript files, but still if I try to launch my program I get that error saying I dont have typescript installed.

If I just run `tsc` in my command prompt or powershell I get some error alerts that I have tried to solve but no luck yet:

```
 tsc
src/App.tsx:12:5 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime' or its corresponding type declarations.

 12     <UserAccountContext.Provider value={guestAccount}>
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 13       <div className="App container">
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 24       </div>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
 25     </UserAccountContext.Provider>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/App.tsx:13:7 - error TS2339: Property 'div' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

13       <div className="App container">
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/App.tsx:15:9 - error TS2339: Property 'div' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

Is there some way I can ensure typescript is installed? Ive tried running the installation commands in both powershell and command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply install in your project by using `yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest` or `npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`.

If you have a problem with the scripts perhaps updating them will solve it, you can try this command: `npm install react-scripts@latest`

For further information you can check this links: [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) and [Typescript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react.html)

Also you may check frameworks that have native support to TS, like [Next](https://nextjs.org/) and [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/)